# Insufficient disk space when restoring a small backup

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm trying to restore a database from 32MB backup. I have 6GB available on my disk. When I'm trying to restore the backup it shows the insufficient disk space error. How is it possible that a 32MB backup requires more than 6GB of disk space?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably because the backup is compressed, or because there is a very large log file that doesn't need to be part of the backup itself, or because the data file itself has been cleaned out - the backup is only comprised of pages that contain data. But when restored, it still has to expand the data file to its original size, even if most of it is empty.

Show us what the size column says when you run:

```
RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = '[path]\whatever.bak';
```

Comment: Can you do compression on SQL Server 2005?

Comment: @Max Maybe with 3rd party tools, or maybe they have 2008 and don't realize.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the problem by shrinking the database before creating backup.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I had a 800 MB database backup file which needed 320 GB  free space to be restored in destination computer.

Turned out it was just because of database log file, to make sure log file is what caused the matter, right click on intended databse and click on properties, after that in `General` tab check `Size` of the database, if it's huge, go to the `Files` tab and navigate to the path of tfiles.

I ran `Shrink` command on database and on files through interface but it didn't help, following query saved me eventually:

```
ALTER DATABASE DataBase_Name SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;
GO
DBCC SHRINKFILE(DataBase_Name_log, 200);
GO
ALTER DATABASE DataBase_Name SET RECOVERY FULL;
GO
```

It means you have to run query on the database, then create a back file once again.

NB: As you see in the query above, Database recovery mode should be on `Simple` before `SHRINKFILE` be executed.

Answer (score 0):

It's always good to double-check which disk you're restoring the mdf and the ldf to, maybe you're creating the files in a full disk, it could happen.

Other than that, I'd suggest restoring that backup in another place, have the files SHRINKed, and backing up it again for a desperate measure.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers explain the reason for the error message but do not provide a solution to the problem. I had the same problem and this is the solution I found.

Plug in an external hard drive with a massive amount of space available, then move the .mdf and .ldf files to the external hard drive. This script can be used to move the files while restoring:

```
RESTORE DATABASE [MyDb] FROM  DISK = N'C:\Data\Backup\MyDb_FULL.bak' WITH  FILE = 1,  MOVE N'MyDb' TO N'E:\Data\MyDb.mdf',  MOVE N'MyDb_log' TO N'E:\Data\MyDb_log.ldf',  NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  STATS = 5
```

Once the database restores successfully to the external drive, you have the option of shrinking the files and then moving them to your hard drive or wherever else you want them to be.