# ms sql increases the required space in different restore tests

Tags: sql-server, restore, space

I tried to restore a DB backup, the bak file is 65GB and restore requires 450GB.
The DB already exists in my sql.
There is not enough space on the disk (290GB), so i tried to drop my existing DB, create DB with a minimun initial space for its files. Now free space is 730GB.
I try to restore and now it requires 1TB!
Why?!

I didn't expect that to increase the space required. how can i solve?

Comment: You'll better search and ask also on https://dba.stackexchange.com for this kind of question. Stackoverflow is mainly for coding specific questions.

Comment: I have added SQL-Server tag for you, because in the title you wrote "ms sql". Is this right? Right tagging will attract the right experts.

Comment: Could be similar to this: https://serverfault.com/questions/79785/excessive-space-required-for-sql-server-bak-restore#79786  or that https://stackoverflow.com/q/15348272/18667225 ?